# Why query is not working as expected in oracle? it return 0 rows although it should return 2 rows

Tags: oracle

I have three table A, B and C. id1 column in table B and C are foreign key to Table A column id.

Please look below structure

Table A:

```
id value
1  1
2  2
3  3
```

Table B:

```
id value            id1
1  2018-04-21-00001   1
2  2018-04-21-00003   1
3  2018-04-21-00009   1
4  2018-04-21-00007   1
5  2018-04-21-00008   1
```

Table C:

```
id2 value2           id1
1  2018-04-21-00001   1
2                     1
3  2018-04-21-00002   1
4                     1
5  2018-04-21-00004   1
6                     1
7  2018-04-21-00006   2
```

Query:

```
select * from B b, C c  
where c.id1 = b.id1 and c.id1 = 1 and 
c.value2 is not null and c.value2 <> b.value
```

I am assuming it should return 2 rows but it is not working as expected. It is returning null rows. Can you please help me in this what 's the issue with the query. Query is in oracle.

Comment: IF I want to fetch records from table C like '2018-04-21-00002' that are not in table B, How do I get it? what's wrong with query of mine. @JNevil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your initial join condition `c.id1 = b.id1` you are going to get a cartesian product at the `id1` level. For your sample data that will be `5*6` or `30` result records.

```
+----+------------------+-----+----+------------------+-----+
| id |      value       | id1 | id |      value2      | id1 |
+----+------------------+-----+----+------------------+-----+
|  1 | 2018-04-21-00001 |   1 |  1 | 2018-04-21-00001 |   1 |
|  1 | 2018-04-21-00001 |   1 |  2 | (null)           |   1 |
|  1 | 2018-04-21-00001 |   1 |  3 | 2018-04-21-00002 |   1 |
|  1 | 2018-04-21-00001 |   1 |  4 | (null)           |   1 |
|  1 | 2018-04-21-00001 |   1 |  5 | 2018-04-21-00004 |   1 |
|  1 | 2018-04-21-00001 |   1 |  6 | (null)           |   1 |
|  2 | 2018-04-21-00003 |   1 |  1 | 2018-04-21-00001 |   1 |
|  2 | 2018-04-21-00003 |   1 |  2 | (null)           |   1 |
|  2 | 2018-04-21-00003 |   1 |  3 | 2018-04-21-00002 |   1 |
|  2 | 2018-04-21-00003 |   1 |  4 | (null)           |   1 |
|  2 | 2018-04-21-00003 |   1 |  5 | 2018-04-21-00004 |   1 |
|  2 | 2018-04-21-00003 |   1 |  6 | (null)           |   1 |
|  3 | 2018-04-21-00009 |   1 |  1 | 2018-04-21-00001 |   1 |
|  3 | 2018-04-21-00009 |   1 |  2 | (null)           |   1 |
|  3 | 2018-04-21-00009 |   1 |  3 | 2018-04-21-00002 |   1 |
|  3 | 2018-04-21-00009 |   1 |  4 | (null)           |   1 |
|  3 | 2018-04-21-00009 |   1 |  5 | 2018-04-21-00004 |   1 |
|  3 | 2018-04-21-00009 |   1 |  6 | (null)           |   1 |
|  4 | 2018-04-21-00007 |   1 |  1 | 2018-04-21-00001 |   1 |
|  4 | 2018-04-21-00007 |   1 |  2 | (null)           |   1 |
|  4 | 2018-04-21-00007 |   1 |  3 | 2018-04-21-00002 |   1 |
|  4 | 2018-04-21-00007 |   1 |  4 | (null)           |   1 |
|  4 | 2018-04-21-00007 |   1 |  5 | 2018-04-21-00004 |   1 |
|  4 | 2018-04-21-00007 |   1 |  6 | (null)           |   1 |
|  5 | 2018-04-21-00008 |   1 |  1 | 2018-04-21-00001 |   1 |
|  5 | 2018-04-21-00008 |   1 |  2 | (null)           |   1 |
|  5 | 2018-04-21-00008 |   1 |  3 | 2018-04-21-00002 |   1 |
|  5 | 2018-04-21-00008 |   1 |  4 | (null)           |   1 |
|  5 | 2018-04-21-00008 |   1 |  5 | 2018-04-21-00004 |   1 |
|  5 | 2018-04-21-00008 |   1 |  6 | (null)           |   1 |
+----+------------------+-----+----+------------------+-----+
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b7798/1

From that result set you say `c.value2 is not null` reducing it to 15 records.

```
+----+------------------+-----+----+------------------+-----+
| id |      value       | id1 | id |      value2      | id1 |
+----+------------------+-----+----+------------------+-----+
|  1 | 2018-04-21-00001 |   1 |  1 | 2018-04-21-00001 |   1 |
|  2 | 2018-04-21-00003 |   1 |  1 | 2018-04-21-00001 |   1 |
|  3 | 2018-04-21-00009 |   1 |  1 | 2018-04-21-00001 |   1 |
|  4 | 2018-04-21-00007 |   1 |  1 | 2018-04-21-00001 |   1 |
|  5 | 2018-04-21-00008 |   1 |  1 | 2018-04-21-00001 |   1 |
|  1 | 2018-04-21-00001 |   1 |  3 | 2018-04-21-00002 |   1 |
|  2 | 2018-04-21-00003 |   1 |  3 | 2018-04-21-00002 |   1 |
|  3 | 2018-04-21-00009 |   1 |  3 | 2018-04-21-00002 |   1 |
|  4 | 2018-04-21-00007 |   1 |  3 | 2018-04-21-00002 |   1 |
|  5 | 2018-04-21-00008 |   1 |  3 | 2018-04-21-00002 |   1 |
|  1 | 2018-04-21-00001 |   1 |  5 | 2018-04-21-00004 |   1 |
|  2 | 2018-04-21-00003 |   1 |  5 | 2018-04-21-00004 |   1 |
|  3 | 2018-04-21-00009 |   1 |  5 | 2018-04-21-00004 |   1 |
|  4 | 2018-04-21-00007 |   1 |  5 | 2018-04-21-00004 |   1 |
|  5 | 2018-04-21-00008 |   1 |  5 | 2018-04-21-00004 |   1 |
+----+------------------+-----+----+------------------+-----+
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b7798/2

Then you say `c.value2 <> b.value` which will leave you with 14 records as only the record where `2018-04-21-00001` will be dropped.

```
+----+------------------+-----+----+------------------+-----+
| id |      value       | id1 | id |      value2      | id1 |
+----+------------------+-----+----+------------------+-----+
|  2 | 2018-04-21-00003 |   1 |  1 | 2018-04-21-00001 |   1 |
|  3 | 2018-04-21-00009 |   1 |  1 | 2018-04-21-00001 |   1 |
|  4 | 2018-04-21-00007 |   1 |  1 | 2018-04-21-00001 |   1 |
|  5 | 2018-04-21-00008 |   1 |  1 | 2018-04-21-00001 |   1 |
|  1 | 2018-04-21-00001 |   1 |  3 | 2018-04-21-00002 |   1 |
|  2 | 2018-04-21-00003 |   1 |  3 | 2018-04-21-00002 |   1 |
|  3 | 2018-04-21-00009 |   1 |  3 | 2018-04-21-00002 |   1 |
|  4 | 2018-04-21-00007 |   1 |  3 | 2018-04-21-00002 |   1 |
|  5 | 2018-04-21-00008 |   1 |  3 | 2018-04-21-00002 |   1 |
|  1 | 2018-04-21-00001 |   1 |  5 | 2018-04-21-00004 |   1 |
|  2 | 2018-04-21-00003 |   1 |  5 | 2018-04-21-00004 |   1 |
|  3 | 2018-04-21-00009 |   1 |  5 | 2018-04-21-00004 |   1 |
|  4 | 2018-04-21-00007 |   1 |  5 | 2018-04-21-00004 |   1 |
|  5 | 2018-04-21-00008 |   1 |  5 | 2018-04-21-00004 |   1 |
+----+------------------+-----+----+------------------+-----+
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b7798/3

This would be more obvious if you built your `WHERE` step by step as I did here.
Instead you are wanting only records from `c` that are not in `b` for `id1 = 1`. So:

```
SELECT *
FROM C c
WHERE c.id1 = 1
  AND c.Value2 IS NOT NULL
  AND c.Value2 NOT IN (SELECT Value FROM B WHERE B.id1 = c.id1);


+----+------------------+-----+
| id |      value2      | id1 |
+----+------------------+-----+
|  3 | 2018-04-21-00002 |   1 |
|  5 | 2018-04-21-00004 |   1 |
+----+------------------+-----+
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b7798/6

Answer (score 0):

What's table A used for?

Properly joined, query does return 2 desired rows:

```
SQL> with b (id, value, id1) as
  2    (select 1, '00001', 1 from dual union all
  3     select 2, '00003', 1 from dual union all
  4     select 3, '00009', 1 from dual union all
  5     select 4, '00007', 1 from dual union all
  6     select 5, '00008', 1 from dual
  7    ),
  8  c (id2, value2, id1) as
  9    (select 1, '00001', 1 from dual union all
 10     select 2, null   , 1 from dual union all 
 11     select 3, '00002', 1 from dual union all
 12     select 4, null   , 1 from dual union all 
 13     select 5, '00004', 1 from dual union all
 14     select 6, null   , 1 from dual union all 
 15     select 7, '00006', 2 from dual           
 16    )
 17  select *
 18  from b join c on b.id = c.id2
 19  where c.id1 = 1
 20    and c.value2 is not null
 21    and c.value2 <> b.value
 22  ;

        ID VALUE        ID1        ID2 VALUE        ID1
---------- ----- ---------- ---------- ----- ----------
         3 00009          1          3 00002          1
         5 00008          1          5 00004          1

SQL>
```